# SHBrowseForFolder with localization for a specific language

Tags: c++, winapi, localization, windows-shell

I use [SHBrowseForFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762115%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API to display folder selection dialog in Windows. My app supports UI language localization based on an end-user's selection. This is achieved by loading all resources using [FindResourceEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648043%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API for a specific LCID.

So I was curious, is there any way to make SHBrowseForFolder honor thread's LCID selection? Or, in any other way make it display text for my preferred language based on LCID?

Comment: It is a Windows dialog.  Your user will have no trouble recognizing it, it speaks his language.  If you need this for localized screenshots then get a license for MSDN or Windows Ultimate so you can get the language packs.

Comment: @HansPassant: They won't have trouble recognizing it, it just looks bad. Say, my Windows user UI language is English. The end-user changes my app's UI to German, but this dialog still shows the window title, cancel button, new folder button in English. I need it displayed in German in this case.

Comment: That German user will have a German language version of Windows. And if he doesn't for some strange reason then he'll be well familiar with that dialog being in another language, he uses it every day.  In fact, he'll think yours looks strange.

Comment: @HansPassant: This question is not about the implementation of my app's UI.

Comment: No.  It is a Windows dialog.  I seem to be repeating myself, over and out.

Comment: @HansPassant: That dialog is shown by my app and that's what an end-user will associate it with. No one cares where it comes from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just curious, who's downvoting it? You guys don't care about localization?

Nonetheless, I think I [found a solution](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18399/Localizing-System-MessageBox). It was suggested to me on a separate thread and it is a C# project designed for `MessageBox` API, but the concept is the same. Install the thread-wide hook before calling `SHBrowseForFolder` using `SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROCRET)` and then trap the `WM_INITDIALOG` notification from the hook procedure. From there simply load your localized text depending on the UI language and set it to controls using `SetDlgItemText`, where `hDlg`=window handle you get in the hook procedure and `nIDDlgItem`=ID of buttons and text fields that need localization. Here are the ones currently used: `IDOK`=OK button, `IDCANCEL`=Cancel button, `0x3746`="Make new folder" button. You can also change the title of the browse window itself by calling `SetWindowText` on the window handle. Then when the `SHBrowseForFolder` returns call `UnhookWindowsHookEx` to unhook from it.

This approach has some drawbacks. One is that it relies on MS to keep the layout of the browse window. So far it's been relatively the same. So you may want to track Windows version with `GetVersionEx` and adapt accordingly.

Secondly, you may need to adjust the sizes of buttons and labels after adding new text. But luckily that is not a problem. Use `DrawText` with the `DT_CALCRECT` flag to see the outlines of a new label and then change each control's size with `MoveWindow`. Note that a more sophisticated approach would involve a full resizing of the browse window itself. But I'll leave it up to you.

In closing, I want to say that it's a shame that Microsoft is so lame in proving decent means of localization of their UI. There are some APIs that were supposedly designed to do that, to name a few:

- [SetThreadLocale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374051%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - I honestly don't know what exactly it does and what is it's purpose. The documentation is close to being moronic.
- [SetThreadUILanguage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374053%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - in despite of having been introduced in Windows XP, this API only does something starting with Windows Vista. But still, it sets only about 80% of the UI to a provided LCID. For instance, `SHBrowseForFolder` is not affected by it, but there may be more. I didn't check other common controls.
- [InitMUILanguage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775699%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - I don't know what this thing does. It had no effect on my app...
- [setlocale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99tb11d%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) - affects only the legacy C stuff like `printf` and such. None of it is used for the UI though.

So here you go. None of it technically works. So a developer forced to write for Windows (and trust me I'd avoid it as soon as I can) who wants to give end-user the capability to change the UI language from their program without resorting to a cumbersome Windows user-wide change of the language, is left to devise his/her own way of doing it. Good going Microsoft!

And lastly, to what @HansPassant suggested above. I cannot make my users pay $100+ just to be able to use their language for my app's UI. I'm sorry, but I can't fall that low...

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, `SHBrowseForFolder()` is not natively user-localizable.  What text within the dialog are you trying to localize exactly?  You have to provide it with a title, so you can provide whatever pre-localized text you want for that.

Are you trying to localize the button captions or other controls, maybe? You would have to use the callback functionality to access and manipulate the dialog controls manually for that.

Have a look at switching to the `IFileOpenDialog` interface.  It has `SetFileNameLabel()` and `SetOkButtonLabel()` methods, at least.

Comment: In the best case scenario I'd expect all of its UI to be localized. But I see your point. I'll probably have to do it manually. Thanks.